# Difference in precision storing Json data: 88.98 is stored as 88.980003

Tags: java, json

It's in the post service:

```
{"baseYearFloatingShareCount":"76876",
  "baseYearStockPrice":"7777777"},
  {"security":
    {"symbol":"tt","id":3},
      "baseYearTotalShareCount":"87987",
      "baseYearFloatingShareCount":"98",
      "baseYearStockPrice":"88.98"
    }
  ],
  "indexCode":"kvfhvhjvyhv",
  "indexName":"jvjvjhvjhv",
  "description":"hvhjgvjhbvjhbv",
  "baseIndex":"76587",
  "sector":{"id":3},
  "calculationType":"FU"}
}
```

This is the JSON data that will be sent for this service

If you could see the Json data, `"baseYearStockPrice":"88.98"` the value is sent with two decimal places, but when it is being stored in DB .. it is stored as `88.9800033569336`.

Please suggest what should be corrected?

Comment: If it should be stored numerically, why are you sending it as a JSON `String`?

Comment: Store it in the database in an integer that denotes the value in cents e.g. 8898.

Comment: (From Review:) I improved the code formatting and the title, also highlighted some code.

Comment: How exactly do you insert that data to your database? Show the code please.

Comment: Hi JJF could u please elaborate little bit more.

Comment: Hi Roman Puchkovshiy,   here is my  Entity class,